# How to redirect output of a bash script to screen on the fly?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm running a one-line script that should have multi-stage output:

```
#!/bin/bash

ansible-playbook deploy-master.yml -i ./inventories --private-key=$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
```

however it won't show anything until its execution is finished (after which it will print all outputs of ansible-playbook). How do I fix this?

Comment: See [this Q&A](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the easiest solution is to switch shebang line to:

## !/usr/bin/env bash

I don't know the reason but it just worked.